# GreenDao select in range with BETWEEN operator

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, greendao

I use GreenDao and I have an entity defined by this class:

```
Dot {
    String name;
    float value;
}
```

And I want to extract from my DataBase all Dots that have a value in between **value - 1 and value + 1**. A SQL query should be something lik this:

```
SELECT * FROM dot WHERE value BETWEEN(value-1, value+1)
```

Can I do the same in GreenDao, maybe:

```
QueryBuilder<Dot> query = DotDao.queryBuilder();
query.where(DotDao.Properties.Value.between(DotDao.Properties.Value-1, DotDao.Properties.Value+1));
List<Range> rangeList = query.list();
```

Is that possible or I have to use some Raw queries?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AND operator.

For example:

```
QueryBuilder<Dot> query = DotDao.queryBuilder();
List<Range> rangeList = query.where(DotDao.Properties.Value.ge(value - 1), DotDao.Properties.Value.le(value + 1))
.list();
```

Details http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/queries/

Comment: The **value** is inside databse. I cannot just write value - 1. My **value** is actually database column name.